# joomla plugin function returns parameter as null

Tags: php, joomla

I'm writting a plugin for Joomla (first time working with Joomla) and I'm having a bit of trouble with something.

Basically what I need is a function in the plugin that returns an url that depends on the plugin parameters. I want to be able to call this function from the site's code like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo plgSystemMyplugin::get_home_url(); ">access</a>
```

and my function looks like this:

```
public function get_home_url () {
    $dn = $this->params->getValue('domainname');
    return 'https://'.$dn.'.mydomain.com';
}
```

but it returns:

```
https://.mydomain.com
```

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Was able to get around it (not sure if its the right way or not but at this point I just want to get it done).

```
public function get_home_url () {
    $plg = JPluginHelper::getPlugin('system', 'myplugin');
    $plg_params = new JRegistry();
    $plg_params->loadString($plg->params);
    $dn = $plg_params->get('domainname');
    return 'https://'.$dn.'.mydomain.com';
}
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($this->params)` and figure out why it's not pulling your domain name through is all I can suggest - basic debugging.

Answer (score 0):

That is a static (belonging to class) call:

```
plgSystemMyplugin::get_home_url();
```

So

```
public function get_home_url()
```

is not accessible this way (because it belongs to instance).

If you make it static as:

```
public static function get_home_url()
```

then you can not access **$this** in get_home_url().

Because, **$this** is one of the dynamic instances not the static class.

Please stop mixing static and dynamic calls and properties.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation, can you help with a solution though? Pointing out the problem is very nice of you and helpful in the long run however its no solution at all. Also, plgSystemMyplugin::get_home_url(); is accessible, it just doesn't return the param with the rest of the string.

Comment: This was a help (any help) and a real answer. The solution is out there in the php manual & on SO & on millions of sites. Do your homework. Do people have to write your code for you?

Comment: Thanks again man, I appreciate the whole "don't give him food, teach him how to fish" however you're not doing that, you're just telling me I'm hungry.

Comment: lol. You have to expose more code if you want an appropriate solution. what is params what is getValue fn etc. This is soo vague.

Comment: I'm gonna jump in here and add some stuff that might help. Okay, so first google the difference between static and public (normal) functions. To use public functions, you first have to **create the class as an object**, then do $object->function(). To use static functions, you don't need to create the object, you just do class::function(). You can't use $this within static functions. They're more just like utility functions that can be called any time from anywhere.

Comment: I do know a bit about coding and dynamic vs static, I'm no expert by any means and php is alien territory for me (I code in objective-c mostly) but the problem I'm having is with joomla because I have no idea how it works, if it instantiates the plugins when rendering the pages or not so I was kind of looking for someone that understands joomla to point out how I can get the plugin parameters from a public function I can access in the front end.

Comment: I understand you don't want to show me how to do it and that's fine, however I don't have time to learn php nor do I want to so I was asking for a 1 line solution on how to access the param which I can then copy/paste into my code and be happy, is that being lazy? Maybe it would be if I had posted this question the moment I needed the code but I did search for a solution for a couple hours now before posting here asking for a 5 secs worth of help so excuse me if I'm a bit cranky when someone points out that the problem is I'm having problems.

Comment: It is not a "do not show him make him do it" ... thing. There are problems with your question which I pointed out in my previous comment.(starting with lol) Now, without you bringing in the correct reference frame into the problem, nobody can solve it without creating one. And this is absolutely not the path I am going to take. Maybe you do not understand what I am telling which is a "know what" problem here. I do not expect you to be php expert and I am sure you are proficient in various fields. But sorry, your question is not solvable at all at this state.

Comment: Ok, that's why I was hoping for someone that knows joomla (which I hate) because when you ask "what is params" and "what is getValue" that is all joomla core stuff, so maybe you're the right person so ask for help with php but just not the right person to ask for help with joomla because I can't be expected to explain joomla's framework right down the the php foundations of it for you to understand, if I knew how to explain that I wouldn't need help with it :D. I'm sorry if I sounded a bit grumpy and I understand you just don't have the knowledge to help with this particular problem.

Comment: You should be able to var_dump() and die; straight after to output what the current variable is to the screen, hence you can trace back to where the root of the problem might be.